Generac Air cooled 16KW generator T1 wiring confirmation. battery not charging
We are in Lake Lure NC and power will be out for some time here.
We are running a Generac but the battery keeps dying and we have to jump it with the car battery. There is no power coming from the T1 line.
Can someone take a look at our wiring here and indicate if the wiring is incorrect? From what I can tell, it appears the T1 and N2 wires are in the wrong spots.
In addition, there is no neutral white) wire for the T1. If I am correct about this, how would I fix it?



what did the Generac customer support say?

We're in the middle of the catastrophic aftermath of Helene in Lake Lure. We're depending on a neighbor with a running generator to get signal to get help with the generator. Generac support says to get an authorized service provider out. The roads are impassable and will be for a long time.

You didn't give a Generac model number or serial number, so I am referring to a random Generac installation manual for an automatic standby 16 KW generator.
The wiring shown in your photo appears to be correct. The manual calls T1 "Fused 120 VAC for battery charger" and the fuse is 7.5 amps, the one on your control panel. You need to check that fuse first of all.
N1 and N2 should be going to your utility's 240V supply to sense a blackout. In the diagram that I found, they are both yellow, though yours look yellow and orange.
Neutral for the battery charger comes from the common neutral lug marked N in the center of the wiring panel below the midpoint. The manual says that N "Must be connected to keep battery charged whether unit is running or not." So if there were issues with floating neutral and ground vs bonded ground when the generator was installed, and this N was disconnected, that's why the battery is not charging.
And finally, go to the control panel and page through from the main menu to the battery menu and display the battery status. Even when there is a low battery warning, the battery status can display either "Good" or "Check battery." If it displays "Check battery", the manual says that the battery must be replaced.
The generator exercises itself periodically and it will set a code if it detects trouble with the battery. The Maintenance schedule calls for checking the battery status periodically. If this has not been checked, you may have had a bad battery for some time.



Thank you. My generator is that exact model. Your diagram shows the T1 and N2 in the top positions for those wires (holes 3 & 5), my T1 and N2 are in the bottom holes (4, and 6). In addition, there is no place for the N wire (please see add photo to post.

You can move the wires from 3 and 5 to 4 and 6 if you want, but the diagrams indicate the holes are in contact pairs; see that 'N1 UTILITY' is marked '1 1' and 'N2 UTILITY' is marked '2 2'; these should be in contact internally. If you move the wires and it works, it's probably because the wires are barely (or not at all) making contact now. Checking the battery and fuses as in this answer is a better use of your time than moving these wires to another hole on the same terminal.

@LauraFrese As Fredric said, there is no difference between the two holes that are provided for each connection. You can connect to either hole. The N wire is in your second photo, the big fat black wire with a white stripe. It is connected, no problem there. NOTE: You can remove the generator's battery and temporarily replace it with a car battery, if the car battery fits in the space. What did you find when you checked the fuse and the control panel battery status?

The battery status is good, we just put a new one in, this is the third battery we have put in over the last few days. The 7.5 amp fuse in the control panel is fine, control panel wont come on if its bad or out. We checked voltage and continuity on the T1 wire and its not showing any AC or DC output both on the generator or the transfer box on the house

@LauraFrese See the new photo below the diagram that explains how two holes for each wire are the same. You can use either hole marked "same".

@LauraFrese The blue wire on T1 should have 120VAC relative to the big fat black wire with the white stripe when you have utility power and possibly when the generator is running. Manual does not confirm the latter. Blue T1 should go to the fuse on the panel. Look for bad splices or crimps both in the blue wire to the fuse and the other wire from the fuse, wherever it goes. Manual does not include a complete wiring diagram. It's basic continuity tracing; sorry I can't help from here, I know what a rough time you are having.

@LauraFrese It seems to me the generator should charge its battery whenever T1 has 120 volts available, regardless of whether that comes from utility or the generator itself. So get a volt meter: while the generator runs, is T1 energized? If not, what is the generator powering, anyway? Perhaps your genny feeds only a critical loads panel, not the whole house -- and T1 is not presently fed from the critical loads panel? Solution could be to re-configure so that T1 is powered from critical loads panel.

This particular generator is an Eaton 16Kwh model that does not have an alternator or any way to charge its own battery while the generator is running, which seems counterproductive. The house utilities, when the power company power works, is supposed to keep the battery charged. We tried to trickle charge the generator battery while its running (off the electricity its generating) but couldnt keep up with the draw. We are trickle charging another battery to use to jump the generator battery. When that doesnt work, we run a secondary small honda generator to charge the house generator battery for a while.

According to the Eaton manual (if this is the right one) there is supposed to be a battery charger built-in:  https://images.eaton.com/ecm/groups/public/@pub/@electrical/documents/content/0h8537.pdf  Section 1.16. Sounds like something is broken. If you can lay hands on a full-size car battery charger instead of a trickle charger, it could quite likely keep up with keeping the alternate battery charged off the generator's output electricity without requiring the other generator.

It doesnt charge itself while running. It is charged off the house power when the house electricity is coming from utility station. The issue is that for some reason the generator just shuts down and the battery is drained. once we recharge the battery from the other generator we can start the eaton and see the error code that threw before shutting down "Low Battery". Perhaps there is a short somewhere that is continuing to drain battery after start?

The battery getting low shouldnt kill the generator. I think thats where the problem is

So the low battery stops the generator? Then there is a low-voltage-generating something in the generator that's supposed to feed the generator's engine electric requirements as well as the battery charging. In a car this part would be the alternator. When a car's alternator goes bad, the battery provides the car's power to ignite the fuel, and can't keep up after a while. It sounds like this generating part in your generator is bad, this does happen. When the generator is running, a full-size (not trickle) battery charger on high current charge should be able to keep up.
